# How to track the progress of a large OrderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard enough dynamically filled table in bootstrap that is instantiated with the following definition

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in controller.items : 
       orderBy:controller.predicate:controller.reverse">...</tr>
</table>
```

And a pretty standard function that, when called with a string argument, will sort the table, using the string argument as the predicate.

```
controller.orderCasesBy = function (predicate) {
    controller.reverse = (controller.predicate === predicate) ? 
        !controller.reverse : false;
    controller.predicate = predicate;
}
```

The page I'm working on potentially has upwards to a thousand rows, so I was trying to figure out a way to track the progress of the ordering function and update a progress bar accordingly.

If this were a case where I was trying to track the progress of the entire table rendering for the first time, I could attach an ng-init function to each repeated row that could update the progress bar whenever it's called.  ng-init functions don't seem to be called when a table is reordered, however, so I was wondering if there was anything I could do to achieve a similar effect.

If I can't, I'd love to hear suggestions on alternative ways to track this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an object parameter to the ordering function, which updates its `value` property (or call it whatever you want), then use the object.value to render your status indicator as you see fit.

Since you said you're open to alternatives, you don't need to actively reverse it at all (and therefore don't need to indicate progress for it). `ngRepeat` allows you to track by index, which means you can simply display them in reverse index order.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in controller.items track by $index">
        <td ng-model="controller.items[controller.items.length-($index+1)]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```